# I have use android:exported="true" but still the Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12

I have faced a problem when I try to run the app the issue is given below.

Error:

Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Here is my manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="33">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".GeneralInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreatePinActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginWithPinActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ResetPinActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LicenceSearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me to resolve the problem as soon as possible.

I try to resolve the issue for that I have use android:exported="true" in intent-filter but I can not able to resolve it Thanks.

Comment: You should check your merged manifest. Maybe one of the libraries that you are using has not added the flag.